# Sum of unit vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

If $\mathbf e_1, ...,\mathbf e_n$ are unit vectors such that $\sum_{i = 1}^n\mathbf e_i = 0$. Find $$\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n}\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$$.

$$S=\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n}\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j = \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = i}^n \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j =\sum_{i = 1}^n\mathbf e_i \cdot \sum_{j = i}^n   \mathbf e_j $$, since $$\sum_{j = i}^n \mathbf e_j + \sum^{i-1}_{j=1} \mathbf e_j=0$$

$$S = -\sum_{i = 1}^n\mathbf e_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1}   \mathbf e_j =-\sum_{i = 1}^n\mathbf e_i \cdot \left(\sum_{j = 1}^{i}   \mathbf e_j - \mathbf e_i \right) =n-\sum_{i = 1}^n\mathbf e_i \cdot \sum_{j = 1}^{i}   \mathbf e_j  $$

How do I evaluate the last sum ?

Is there a geometric way of evaluating this sum ?

Comment: Already your first double sum is false.

Comment: Use symmetry (i.e. $\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j = \mathbf e_j \cdot \mathbf e_i$) and find a rleation between $2\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n}\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$ and the sum $\sum_{1 \le i , j \le n}\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$ over all pairs i,j.

Comment: @amsmath Why ? $ $

Comment: Because it should be $\sum_i\sum_{j\ge i}$.

Comment: @amsmath You mean $\sum_i^n\sum_{j\ge i}$ right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we only know $\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf e_i$ so we need to find a relation between $\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n}\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$:

For any $i \ne j$, there are two $\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$ in $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$. So if we time $2$ to $\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n}\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$ then we can guarantee that for $i \ne j$ then there are two $\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$.

However, note that for $i=j$ there is only one $\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_i$ in $\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$. But $2\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n}\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j$ has two $\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_i$. Thus, we must take one out.

In conclusion, we obtain
\begin{align*} 2\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n} \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j & =\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j+\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf e_i^2, \\
& = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{e_i} \right)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n1, \\
&=n.
\end{align*}
Thus, $\sum_{1 \le i  \le j \le n} \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j=n/2$.

Comment: In $\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=i}$ we have one $e_1\cdot e_2$ for $i = 1$ and $j= 2$, can you tell me for which value of $i,j$ we get the other $e_1\cdot e_2$ ?

Comment: You're right. I misread your approach. So your approach is not wrong, but I don't think it can get you anywhere. You can see the proof in my post, in which it is $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n$ instead.

Comment: Yes you are right and have a better approach. I asked because I can't figure out why my double sum is wrong.